# Invalid column name - Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, token, nltk

I'm a beginner at coding or machine learning and I'm struggling with my code. I would like to remove random word from a column which also contain sometimes integer or float (it's a column of an email exchange), and next ask BERT to add words that match, to do a data augmentation, but I have a problem in my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

# lire les données de la colonne Excel en utilisant pandas
df = pd.read_excel("Output_Summarization/OUTPUT_ocr_OPENAIGOOD.xlsx", usecols="Open_AI_Text")

# itérer sur chaque ligne de la colonne
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  # tokeniser le texte de la ligne en mots individuels
  words = word_tokenize(row["Open_AI_Text"])

  # choisir un mot au hasard à enlever
  word_to_remove = random.choice(words)

  # enlever le mot du texte
  new_text = row["Open_AI_Text"].replace(word_to_remove, "")

  # mettre à jour la ligne dans le DataFrame
  df.at[index, "Open_AI_Text"] = new_text

# enregistrer le DataFrame mis à jour dans un nouveau fichier Excel
df.to_excel("Texte_Trou.xlsx", index=False)
```

I'm 100% it'ss my column name, as I can use it if I write df['Open_AI_Text'].
The problem written is :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-e9ccdb1ab0b2> in <module>
      4 
      5 # lire les données de la colonne Excel en utilisant pandas
----> 6 df = pd.read_excel("Output_Summarization/OUTPUT_ocr_OPENAIGOOD.xlsx", usecols="Open_AI_Text")
      7 
      8 # itérer sur chaque ligne de la colonne

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    294                 )
    295                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 296             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    297 
    298         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols)
    332         skipfooter=skipfooter,
    333         convert_float=convert_float,
--> 334         mangle_dupe_cols=mangle_dupe_cols,
    335     )
    336 

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in parse(self, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    924             convert_float=convert_float,
    925             mangle_dupe_cols=mangle_dupe_cols,
--> 926             **kwds,
    927         )
    928 

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in parse(self, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    442 
    443             data = self.get_sheet_data(sheet, convert_float)
--> 444             usecols = _maybe_convert_usecols(usecols)
    445 
    446             if not data:

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_util.py in _maybe_convert_usecols(usecols)
    146 
    147     if isinstance(usecols, str):
--> 148         return _range2cols(usecols)
    149 
    150     return usecols

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_util.py in _range2cols(areas)
    117             cols.extend(range(_excel2num(rng[0]), _excel2num(rng[1]) + 1))
    118         else:
--> 119             cols.append(_excel2num(rng))
    120 
    121     return cols

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_util.py in _excel2num(x)
     82 
     83         if cp < ord("A") or cp > ord("Z"):
---> 84             raise ValueError(f"Invalid column name: {x}")
     85 
     86         index = index * 26 + cp - ord("A") + 1

ValueError: Invalid column name: Open_AI_Text
```

I tried to just use df[Open_AI_Text] as df but then this problem appeared :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-17e13b68c999> in <module>
      9 
     10 # itérer sur chaque ligne de la colonne
---> 11 for index, row in df.iterrows():
     12   # tokeniser le texte de la ligne en mots individuels
     13   words = word_tokenize(row["Open_AI_Text"])

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5137             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5138                 return self[name]
-> 5139             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5140 
   5141     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

Sorry again, I'm a total beginner in an internship

Comment: Salut julie! Elcome to SO. Would you please post a reproducible minimal example of your data? You can for instance do this by doing a print of you dataframe and post it just as you would do with code.

Answer (score 0):

You’re using the wrong kind of value for the `usecols` attribute. Check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

usecols: str, list-like, or callable, default None

If None, then parse all columns.

If str, then indicates comma separated list of Excel column letters and column ranges (e.g. “A:E” or “A,C,E:F”). Ranges are inclusive of both sides.

If list of int, then indicates list of column numbers to be parsed (0-indexed).

If list of string, then indicates list of column names to be parsed.

If callable, then evaluate each column name against it and parse the column if the callable returns True.

Returns a subset of the columns according to behavior above.